# The use of preposition in this case

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Do I always need a preposition when I say..

"I traveled (in) NY?"

Can I simply say, "I traveled NY"?

Comment: You don't need a preposition when you say *"traveled the world"*, but I think that's a special case. [Consider this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=traveled+the+world%2Ctraveled+in+Europe%2Ctraveled+Europe%2Ctraveled+in+the+world&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctraveled%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctraveled%20in%20Europe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctraveled%20Europe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctraveled%20in%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0). You get nearly the same results if you spell travelled with 2 l's, showing the grammar is the same in the U.K.

Comment: What do you find when you carry out a Google search for "travel(l)ed New York"? Are the first results relevant?

Comment: @Peter  The transitive (or surface-transitive, if seen as prepositional deletions?) constructions "travel(l)ed the continent" and certainly  "travelled the state" are not uncommon. I think it's the 'journeyed across' sense. Probably, substituting individual states would not be seen as unacceptable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But *travelled the West Country* has a different meaning to *travelled to the West Country*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I agree.  Could you make this an Answer, please?

Comment: If you visited New York from Washington, you traveled *to* New York.  If you went from Albany to Springfield, you traveled *in* New York.  If you spent two weeks going from one edge of the state to the other, visiting many sights, you "traveled New York".

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that there is a difference in meaning.

> I travelled in New York (State) = I went here and there in NY State.

but

> I travelled New York (State) = I covered most of the state. I journeyed widely.

The transitive (or surface-transitive, if seen as prepositional deletions?) constructions "travel(l)ed the world", "travelled the continent" and certainly "travelled the state" are not uncommon. I think it's the 'journeyed widely throughout', 'covered the length and breadth of' sense. Probably, substituting individual states would not be seen as unacceptable. Anything smaller, like a region, wouldn't sound too good (*/?I travelled the Brecon Beacons) (though the preposition chosen here might well be 'around').

Answer (score 0):

The way that sounds correct should be "traveled to NY", but if you mean you traveled inside the boundary of NY, "traveled in NY" should be correct.
 I hope I helped. :)

Answer (score -1):

The use, or not, of the preposition depends on your intended sense. If you want to convey that you traversed NY, no preposition is needed. If you want to convey that you traveled inside NY, the preposition is needed.

From [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/travel):

> travel
>
> v.intr.
>
> 1. a. To go from one place to another, as on a trip; journey.
>
> v.tr.
>
> To pass or journey over or through; traverse

Comment: I think the v. tr. definition is meant for constructions like *"traveled the king's road"* or *"traveled the New Jersey turnpike"*, not *"traveled New York"*.

Comment: I think you're putting the cart before the horse. Although I cite the dictionary as a reference and use it as a device to save myself the work of distilling or extracting definitions, what informs (and sometimes misinforms) my understanding of what words mean is how I've encountered them in use.

Comment: @PeterShor, Here are three (of the many possible) extant uses illustrating the case: "Jake traveled New York State ..." [Blackman Upick Apple Farm](http://www.blackmanhomesteadfarm.com/whats_new_blackman_farm.html); "Hochul, who has traveled New York State ..." [FIT Newsroom](http://news.fitnyc.edu/2015/05/11/governor-cuomo-congresswoman-nancy-pelosi-address-sexual-violence/); "The photographer Paul Nathan and his wife Nadine Rubin Nathan have traveled New York ..." [HuffPost Books](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/03/07/couture-dogs-of-new-york-_n_2823347.html).

Comment: ... and in ***none*** of these three uses does it mean they traversed New York, if by traverse you mean go through New York on your way to somewhere else. I see there is another definition of *traverse New York* which does match what *travel New York* actually means when it is used (but that definition wouldn't contrast with *traveled inside New York*).

Comment: @PeterShor, your second sight (forgive the word play) is mostly accurate; and again, you've reversed the actual way things work. In an absolute sense, my use determines the definition, not the other way around. Obviously, there's a feedback loop with the dictionary as a reference (and a lexicon as a compilation) and the actual senses of words in use, but the second, not the former, is the original source.

Comment: I really don't understand this.  If you traveled in NY use "in."  If you went through it or across it, use those prepositions.  Why leave them out and cause confusion, and have to hunt around on the Internet or style books for justification?

Comment: @michael_timofeev, that's an interesting question. Let me answer it (perhaps) by asking you if, after you've visited a National Forest, you've traveled *on* or *in* the National Forest--that is, not the forest itself, but the geopolitically defined area? Do you understand any distinction between the prepositional senses in that case?

Comment: You can't travel "on" a forest.  You travel through or in a forest.  I just don't get this.   "I traveled across NY this summer" or "I traveled in NY this summer." are both grammatically correct and easily recognizable as such even by non-experts.  The other possibility isn't something we all agree upon, and if I were an ESL learner I would want a safe and sure answer, not "Well, maybe," "It could be under certain circumstances not always encountered," or "that's an interesting point depending on whether it's a blah blah blah verb."  Just my two cents worth.

Comment: Also, by changing the original verb "travelled" to "traversed" you are changing the sentence.  Traversed means to cross and doesn't require a preposition but this doesn't mean that travelled now doesn't require a preposition.  What if the verb were "ran?"  "I ran the school halls," or "I ran California."  Does that work?

Answer (score -2):

No one would argue the validity of "Traveled in NY." However no one is really sure about "Traveled NY."  Go with the tried and true way.